# How to select 2nd element with same tag using dom xpath?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I have layout like this:

```
<div class="fly">
    <img src="a.png" class="badge">
    <img class="aye" data-original="b.png" width="130" height="253" />        
         <div class="to">
              <h4>Fly To The Moon</h4>
                  <div class="clearfix">
                       <div class="the">
                            <h4>**Wow**</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="moon">
                            <h4>**Great**</h4>                      
                       </div>
                   </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

First I get query from xpath :

```
$a = $xpath->query("//div[@class='fly']""); //to get all elements in class fly    
foreach ($a as $p) {
     $t = $p->getElementsByTagName('img');
     echo ($t->item(0)->getAttributes('data-original'));
}
```

When I run the code, it will produced 0 result. After I trace I found that `<img class="badge">` is processed first. I want to ask, how can I get data-original value from `<img class="aye">`and also get the value "**Wow**" and "**Great**" from `<h4>` tag?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Alernatively, you could use another xpath query on that to add on your current code.

To get the attribute, use `->getAttribute()`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$parent_div = $xpath->query("//div[@class='fly']"); //to get all elements in class fly

foreach($parent_div as $div) {
    $aye = $xpath->query('./img[@class="aye"]', $div)->item(0)->getAttribute('data-original');
    echo $aye . '<br/>'; // get the data-original
    $others = $xpath->query('./div[@class="to"]/div[@class="clearfix"]', $div)->item(0);
    foreach($xpath->query('./div/h4', $others) as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue . '<br/>'; // echo the two h4 values
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BTJjeP)

Comment: Ghost, do you know how to parse data from jquery ajax return? it's hidden in the html tag. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewB.O. what do you mean didn't work? have you seen the demo? and regarding that hidden input, no dynamic values rendered by an ajax cannot be parsed this way, you'll need to use phantomjs or selenium to do that

Comment: yes. I have seen the demo, but when I adopt your code to my case (which is illustrated by the layout) it gives different result. So, I change bit of your code. Many many thank you for your help :) PhantomJS runs on client side and I parse the document on server side. How can I use that?

Comment: @AndrewB.O. to be quite honest that was just a suggestion, you're going to have to discover it yourself since i haven't been assigned to any projects that will utilize that. i'm guessing you'll just have to pass them thru an xmlhttprequest

Comment: thank you so much for your idea. I search url from firebug and then I use that url to be parsed. It works.

Comment: @AndrewB.O. glad this gave you an idea, no prob

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your code!

I try the code but it fails, I don't know why. So, I change a bit of your code and it works!

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$parent_div = $xpath->query("//div[@class='fly']"); //to get all elements in class fly

foreach($parent_div as $div) {
    $aye = $xpath->query('**descendant::**img[@class="aye"]', $div)->item(0)->getAttribute('data-original');
    echo $aye . '<br/>'; // get the data-original
    $others = $xpath->query('**descendant::**div[@class="to"]/div[@class="clearfix"]', $div)->item(0);
    foreach($xpath->query('.//div/h4', $others) as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeValue . '<br/>'; // echo the two h4 values
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

I have no idea what is the difference between `./` and `descendant` but my code works fine using `descendant`.

Answer (score 0):

given the following XML:

```
<div class="fly">
    <img src="a.png" class="badge">
    <img class="aye" data-original="b.png" width="130" height="253" />        
         <div class="to">
              <h4>Fly To The Moon</h4>
                  <div class="clearfix">
                       <div class="the">
                            <h4>**Wow**</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="moon">
                            <h4>**Great**</h4>                      
                       </div>
                   </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

you asked:

> how can I get `data-original` value from `<img class="aye">`and also get the value "Wow" and "Great" from `<h4>` tag?

With XPath you can obtain the values as string directly:

```
string(//div[@class='fly']/img/@data-original)
```

This is the string from the first data-original attribute of an img tag within all divs with class="fly".

```
string(//div[@class='fly']//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][1])
string(//div[@class='fly']//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][2])
```

These are the string values of first and second `<h4>` tag that is not followed on it's own level by another `<h4>` tag within all divs `class="fly"`.

This looks a bit like standing in the way right now, but with iteration, those parts in front will not be needed any longer soon because the xpath then will be relative:

```
//div[@class='fly']
    string(./img/@data-original)
    string(.//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][1])
    string(.//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][2])
```

To use xpath `string(...)` expressions in PHP you must use [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/DOMXPath.evaluate) instead of `DOMXPath::query()`. This would then look like the following:

```
$aye  = $xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='fly']/img/@data-original)");
$h4_1 = $xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='fly']//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][1])");
$h4_2 = $xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='fly']//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][2])");
```

A full example with iteration and output:

```
// all <div> tags with class="fly"
$divs = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@class='fly']");

foreach ($divs as $div) {

    // the first data-original attribute of an <img> inside $div
    echo $xpath->evaluate("string(./img/@data-original)", $div), "<br/>\n";

    // all <h4> tags anywhere inside the $div
    $h4s = $xpath->evaluate('.//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)]', $div);

    foreach ($h4s as $h4) {
        echo $h4->nodeValue, "<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

As the example shows, you can use evaluate as well for node-lists, too. Obtaining the values from all `<h4>` tags it not with `string()` any longer as there could be more than just two I assume.

[Online Demo including special string output (just exemplary)](http://3v4l.org/7nPfr):

```
echo <<<HTML
{$xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='fly']/img/@data-original)")}<br/>
    {$xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='fly']//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][1])")}<br/>
    {$xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='fly']//h4[not(following-sibling::*//h4)][2])")}<br/>
<hr/>
HTML;
```